# How to combine text vector parameter with other parameters before feeding it to sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I'm trying to combine two types of parameters before clustering.

My parameters are Text - represented as sparse matrix,
and another array representing other features of my data point.

I've tried to combine the 2 types of parameters into 1 array and passing it as an input to the algo:

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=1, min_samples=3, metric=get_distance).fit(array(combined_list))
```

Also I've built a custom distance metric which I'm going to use.

```
def get_distance(vec1,vec2):
    text_distance = cosine_similarity(vec1[0] ,vec2[0])
    other_distance = vec1[1]-vec2[1]

    return (text_distance+other_distance)/2
```

But I'm getting an error when trying to pass my input array.
The combined array was constructed as following:

```
combined_list = []
for i in range(len(hashes_list)):
    combined_list.append((hashes_list[i],text_list[i]))

combined_list = array(combined_list)
```

**Full Error Traceback:**

```sh
db = DBSCAN(eps=1, min_samples=3, metric=get_distance ).fit(array(combined_list))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/tal/src/campaign_detection/Data_Extractor/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/dbscan_.py", line 319, in fit
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
  File "/Users/tal/src/campaign_detection/Data_Extractor/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 527, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
  File "/Users/tal/src/campaign_detection/Data_Extractor/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Is this the correct approach for combining text vector with other parameters?

Comment: can add the code on how you create `combined_list`? and complete error traceback!

Comment: added clarifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have couple of suggestions for your approach.

1. Input for DBSCAN has to be fed with array of 2D and not tuples. Hence you have to flatten your input data.

[From Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.fit):

> **X :** array or sparse (CSR) matrix of shape (n_samples, n_features), or array of shape 
>   (n_samples, n_samples)

2. `get_distance()` has to return single value and not a array. Hence, I would suggest you to use some measure for not text features. I have given an example for euclidean distance.

**Example:**

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> corpus = [
...     'This is the first document.',
...     'This document is the second document.',
...     'And this is the third one.',
...     'Is this the first document?',
... ]
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
>>> text_list = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)


import numpy as np
hashes_list = np.array([[12,12,12],
               [12,13,11],
               [12,1,16],
               [4,8,11]])

from scipy.sparse import hstack
combined_list = hstack((hashes_list,text_list))

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

n1 = len(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

def get_distance(vec1,vec2):
    text_distance = cosine_similarity([vec1[:n1]], [vec2[:n1]])
    other_distance = euclidean_distances([vec1[n1:]], [vec2[n1:]])
    return (text_distance+other_distance)/2

db = DBSCAN(eps=1, min_samples=3, metric=get_distance ).fit(combined_list.toarray())
```

Comment: Thanks! thats working great.  hstack is what I needed!